# how to fit a picture in a website in a consistent manner

Tags: html, css

Very new to website design and am making a website. In this website I put a background image to my header, and the portion of the image displayed is changed when the monitor or resolution is changed. How can i consistently have the same portion of the image showing?

Comment: Ideally background-size:cover should serve the purpose. but still it would be better if you could post a snippet of the problem

Comment: I will post the html and css along with website snaps

Comment: If you're very new to website design, do some research on google and look at multiple sources. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp) is one of those resources and has some examples as well, but do more research on the internet over multiple sources. Sometimes you learn other approaches or better techniques.

Comment: HI guys, I've solved the problem and have moved on. Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score -2):

you can use `backgroung-position: center;` or whatever. or you can use `background-size: cover;`. these should help if you try all values!